# React Navigation SwitchNavigator - navigate between several stacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I had to refactor recently the navigation inside my React Native App using React Navigation.

Indeed, I have several navigators inside my app for different purposes: screens when not connected, screens when connected and some screens that should be available in both situations 
(e.g. terms of use).

So my question is the following, if I have this pattern, how can I for example navigate from `TermsOfUse` to `Register` without going back to `Welcome`?

I can't use `navigate.goBack()` or `navigation.navigate('Register')` since those screens are not in the same `StackNavigator`, and duplicate the TermsOfUse in both navigators would be quite dirty.

```
// Screens
const NotConnectedScreens = {
  Welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
  Register: { screen: RegisterScreen },
}

const ConnectedScreens = {
  Homepage: { screen: HomepageScreen },
  Tutorial: { screen: TutorialScreen },
}

const OthersScreens = {
  TermsOfUse: { screen: TermsOfUseScreen },
}

// Stacks
const NotConnectedStack = createStackNavigator(NotConnectedScreens, {
  initialRouteName: 'Welcome',
})

const ConnectedScreens = createStackNavigator(ConnectedScreens, {
  initialRouteName: 'Homepage',
})

const OtherStack = createStackNavigator(OtherScreens, {
  initialRouteName: 'TermsOfUse',
})

// App navigation
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      NotConnectedStack: NotConnectedStack,
      ConnectedStack: ConnectedStack,
      OthersStack: OthersStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'LandingStack',
      defaultNavigationOptions: {
        header: null,
        headerMode: 'none',
      },
    }
  )
)

export { AppContainer as default }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't use navigate.goBack() or navigation.navigate('Register') since
>   those screens are not in the same StackNavigator.

Not completely true, if your screen has a unique name, wherever you need to navigate to that page you can call the function `this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondPage')`.

but sometimes going to an screen from another stack can't be done because it needs some data to be passed when navigating to. in this case MAKE SURE YOUR SCREEN HAS A DIFFERENT NAME

```
DevicesList: {screen: DevicesList },// this is wrong
DevicesListPage: {screen: DevicesList },// this is right
```

then you can navigate to that page like below from another stack:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('DevicesListPage', { 
        //your data
       });
```

Comment: Imagine that I have some info filled in in the registration page and I want to look at the terms of use that are in a different page. After reading, I want to go back to my registration form. Is there a way to use `navigation.goBack()` so I don't lose my form data ?

Comment: i'm not really sure but i don't think so, because i assume the stack will be lost if you navigate to another page from other stack. i advise you to search more to make sure of that.